# What devices/browsers to target with a responsive layout

Tags: testing, responsive-design, target-platform

I am writing a detailed estimate for a client (project has been accepted but it is now a matter of explaining the different functionalities) to develop a responsive layout website.

It is not my first development of that kind, but this one is a key account and path must be paved.

The layout will adapt from 300px width to 1200+px and thus virtually to "any" device and browser, but i am a little lost on my commitment to that. With desktop websites it is easy to write in your contract that the supported browsers will be "IE7+, up-to-date versions of FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera", but what do you write about a responsive website?

I have a bunch of devices that i know i'll perform tests with (let's say a PC, a Mac, iPad, iPhone, 2 or 3 Android devices) but what do i say to my client?
I can't write that the "website will work on any device", nor can I give an exhaustive list of the combinations of devices/browsers it will work on. And i don't want to be stuck with "*my uncle has seen the website on his 2.2 Android old phone and it doesn't work"*.

There are a lot of desktop tools around to simulate various viewports and perform tests on, but they hardly work as the "real thing" ; or is there one standard we developers can refer to "contractually"? How do you manage that and what are your commitments towards your clients?

Answer (score 2):

Take on a Progressive Enhancement approach for development. It isn't possible to get a website to be pixel perfect and work the same on every single browser.

Take of a tiered approach (Gold/Silver/Bronze). Old and untested browsers will get the content (IE7, older blackberry, older anything). Newish browsers get content and layout nice (IE8/9, Firefox < 4). And Modern browsers get a typical nice modern website.

It's possible to set this up with appropriate thinking. Build it from the bottom up. Bronze  to Silver  to Gold. Start with the very minimum setup (only colour, font, text. No divs, no layout, nada). This is your bronze. Next get the silver level setup. Include layout. This layout would be for smaller screens. And finally we would have gold. This would include media queries for larger screens and JS for increased usability and niceties.

It is possible to split between Bronze and Silver for the layout by wrapping your layout within @media only screen{} query. Older browsers do not understand it. The content still appears on those browsers. To split between Silver and Gold it's simply put in a min-width media query and you're set.

Also, ensure that the client understands the definition of "website will work on any device". Just because Opera Mini doesn't support line-height doesn't mean the site doesn't work on it. Here is an article that Brad Frost wrote on that subject: Support vs Optimization: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/support-vs-optimization/

I hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 2):

**What devices/browsers to target with a responsive layout**
You should be targeting a minimal resolution and not a device or browser. You should re-size your design and watch for the design to no longer work comfortably and then use media queries to respond and adapt the design.

**Clients:**
I think ideally you're looking for a way to explain the concept to customers. What you need to do is communicate the goal, which is to provide the best experience possible. I have found that you should be honest with your customer, let them know that you are following industry best practices and the design will be "functional" across the majority of devices and browsers on the market.

Here is a blurb that I like to use:

> Compatibility across platforms: Due to the vast number of web
>   browsers, platforms and devices, the user experience of the website
>   may change to best fit the viewing platform.

If you would like to explain, or are asked to explain what this means, I would say:

> We(I) always use best practices to meet industry standards for web
>   design. We(I) do our(my) best to insure that the design will be
>   "functional" on all main stream platforms. Because of the increasingly
>   vast number of web accessible devices available, I can not guarantee
>   that the design will look identical from one device to another.

You must also consider that new devices are created all the time. So you don't want to make your statement too concrete or you will be retrofitting you designs to accommodate the next iWatch or iFridge that hits the market.

Remember to communicate what is really important, that the content gets displayed. For the most part text and images should work almost anywhere. It's the fancy stuff like shadows, rounded corners, video (IE7), and media queries that don't always work but shouldn't obscure content.

Also, web applications can be a bit tricker since some form elements don't work across devices & browsers. (ex: File uploads).

Hopefully this helps.

*I'm not a contract lawyer, you may want to run this across a paralegal or law savvy friend for further advice.*

Comment: Thank you, this gets closer to the kind of answer i was expecting. @DevonRW i am familiar with what you link me to, i.e. progressive enhancement etc, but what i'm seeking here is more about how to deal with my client = how to explain to them what i'm doing with responsive design and most importantly what to commit to regarding the platforms/browsers that we'll "support". I reckon this is less of a pure development question and more of a "business" question so don't hesitate to point me to a different QA site if relevant, but i was interested in developers answers is why i asked it on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Having gone through this experience a lot of times these are the key points i tend to show to client to make them understand the concept.

1. What is cross browser, platform (OS), screen resolution and device screen size. I tend to take latest screenshots or links of W3C stats to show them some trends in past 2 years and where this market is going. it clearly convince them that they need a responsive layout.
2. If they want further evidence to these i show them twitter bootstrap and jquery UI and jquery mobile sites on at least 2-3 devices using Adobe Edge Inspect. Laptop, Tablet and Phone can be all on same network and just browse through the site to show them how it responds to different sizes.
3. I have a list of pros and cons collected over time for IE7, IE6, Chromeframe, Android native browser vs Chrome on Android, IPhone4 vs iPhone5 browser. usually i see which way they are more inclined and if its phone i will make them aware of pros and cons of that market. Most of the time they should understand that its not an app but a responsive site.
4. When you are writing a proposal do not put in "We will cover for all devices". You can never do that. Be realistic. Create virtaul machine and simulators to test at least the framework you are going to use before making these claims in writing. Setting up VM or Virtual Box is free and you can get Linux and eclipse or netbeans to run dummy phone and tablet and browse your framework on it.
5. For screen resolution and screen size again W3C stats are very realistic and convincing. Use them and use Resolution test kind of plugins in firefox or chrome and take some screenshots of your past work or just the framework so you can at least show the goodness involved or limitation of what can be done and cannot be done.

Most of the answers here are quite right just wanted to add how you can use both W3C and statistics to convince on the route for responsive layout. There are more than million sample sites online to convince people now and for past 6 month i have found that people do get convinced by step 1 alone.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite clear. Your client wants a modern website. However, all browsers don't support all the modern features. Your client wants to spend money wise and have a site that improve through time. Not grow old soon and new bugs emerge as new browsers are released. This is why Graded Browser Support is for: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Site will be usable with all the browsers. Mainstream browsers will get enhanced user experience. Most modern browsers will get the super cool newest goodies.

Let the client know, the more you "hack" the site to get some feature to work with some defect old browser, the more likely it will break on the new ones. It's not worth the time and money.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do when designing responsive websites.

When an old or unsupported browser is detected, the website will simply exclude the jQuery elements that make it responsive, so the result is a fixed width site.

Now, what do you tell your client?

Just be frank. Tell them you made your website responsive for the modern devices out there. For the older devices, their website wont be so good-looking. Show them a couple of examples too. Some big companies, simply display a alert telling the user their browser it outdated and the website won't work properly. One example is Google.

So, essentially, your website works with all devices, but looks better and is responsive on the modern devices and browsers out there.